# In the context of fixed-width _fastN_t types, explain how a "designated type may not be the fastest for all purposes"

Tags: c

I have been wondering whether any _fastN_t type, which is of equal or narrower width than int, is guaranteed to be an int,

so I went to read the Standard, and it said:

> Each of the following types designates an integer type that is usually fastest<sup>225</sup>) to operate with among all integer types that have at least the specified width.

But the 225 footnote said something that confused me and made me worry:

> The designated type is not guaranteed to be fastest for all purposes; if the implementation has no clear grounds for choosing one type over another, it will simply pick some integer type satisfying the signedness and width requirements.

Is this something I should worry about, or does it relate to weird types like floats and/or weird architectures or weird compilers? Explain what the writers meant with the footnote 225.

Comment: Hi. `Explain what the writers meant with the footnote 225.` What exactly is unclear to you  in the footnote? "The types are not guaranteed to be the fastest for all purposes". What exactly is unclear in that sentence? I am not clear what explanation I can give except paraphrasing.

Comment: It’s not something you really need to worry about unless you’re writing a compiler for a new chip or something similarly esoteric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance is not one-size-fits-all.  As a concrete example:

```
struct foo {
    int_fast32_t numbers[8];
};
struct foo arr[50];
```

`sizeof(foo)` is probably 32 or 64 bits.  Which one is faster on x86-64?

1. 32 bits, because it has a smaller cache/memory footprint.
2. 64 bits, because the program has 50 threads which each write to their own `foo`, and 64 bits is the size of a cache line so this avoids false sharing.

In the above example (one of many we could construct), there is no single "fastest" width the compiler can define for all use cases.

Answer (score 2):

> whether any _fastN_t type, which is of equal or narrower width than int, is guaranteed to be an int,

No.

Counter example - on gcc on x86_64 `int_fast8_t` is `signed char`.

> Is this something I should worry about

No.

> does it relate to weird types like floats and/or weird architectures or weird compilers?

No.

> Explain what the writers meant with the footnote 225.

Compiler writers are just choosing *some* correct type for `int_fastN_t` types. Bottom line, the "speed" of the type depends on the exact architecture instructions the compiler chooses to work with that type. Choosing some other type than `int_fastN_t` might be faster in specific contexts.